# Output view into another into another through MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I am a beginner with MVVM integration on Windows Phone. I have 2 different views( TilesView[xaml+cs] and MainPage[xaml+cs] ) and 2 ViewModels (MainViewModel.cs and TilesViewModel.cs) then my MainPage.xaml .
I want to output the TilesView into my MainPage when the home button on the MainPage is pressed. The TilesView contains a Canvas which has my tiles. What control in my MainView should I use so it will contain the TilesView?
I want a function named LaodTiles to be called whenever I want to output the view into the MainPage after the HomeButton in that MainPage is pressed. How do I define that function and where?

I primarily integrated the MVVM structure to be able to better manage my resources and make the MainPage as light as possible so it would load faster when my application is launched by controlling what design components should be launched first and what should be delayed. The Tiles view is what I removed from the MainPage and have it load later, and when closed it will free up some resources.

So I managed to do the MVVM wiring in the VMLocator this way (please, correct me if this is not the way to proceed) :

```
...
public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TilesHomeViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public TilesHomeViewModel TilesVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TilesHomeViewModel>();
        }
    }
...
```

My TilesView has this general structure:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="myAppName.Views.TilesHomeView" ... >
    <Grid x:Name="HomeGrid" ...>
        <Canvas x:Name="TilesCanvas" >
        ...
```

In my TilesHomeViewModel, I set it at INotifyPropertyChanged (again, I am a beginner with MVVM so my understanding on how to tackle this issue might be off) . Here is how it is defined:

```
public class TilesHomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string loadHomeContent;
    public string LoadHomeContent
    {
        get
        {
            return loadHomeContent;
        }
        set
        {
            loadHomeContent = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LoadHomeContent");
        }
    }

    public TilesHomeViewModel()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

My MainPage.xaml has a spot where a grid having gridrows defined. Gridrow=0 has been reserved for TilesView, so when TilesView will popup/load into the MainPage, it will fill that gridrow section. If reserving a gridrow space is not a solution or not necessary, I would be glad to hear some other tip/solution. Maybe there is another way to have the TilesView repositioned whenever it is called like in codebehind.

Any tip, code or tutorial links to those questions asked earlier will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a large scale Windows Phone App (MapQuest) and the design philosophy the other developer and myself came up was to use MVVM, but with only one view/page and would simply load all views (as controls in this case) by setting their visibility as needed which to the end user appeared to step through pages.

With that said, there is no one way of doing things and your way may be just as valid as anyone elses'. I recommend you do something similar as mentioned above and keep to one page, but continue to utilizes multiple ViewModels, or one view model with all data as needed but swap out visible views.

As to processing the views, do that in the mainpage codebehind to turn of each view/control.

Or have each control (view) bind to an enum on the viewmodel which provides a view state. Each control (your view) will take what the enum returns and knows whether to make itself visible or not depending on the state.

You will need to place a dependency property on the target user control/view(s) for that enum. I recommend installing these snippets from [Helpful Silverlight Snippets](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/) (don't worry I have used them for Silverlight, WPF an WP8 code) into visual studio. You will need to add A value type dependency property with change handler for the above enum and in the change handler turn on or off the control.

Don't get too hung up on MVVM, its just a fancier way of doing 3 tiered architecture of separating business logic from view logic from processing logic. The main thing is to bind to the VM and do most of the processing on the VM for data, but not direct view logic, except to turn on or off data bound on the View for that processing.

Comment: I installed the snippets thanks. Will look into how they work.
And what you recommended/described is exactly the way I want to proceed. But my problem is that I have no idea what control have I to use in my view which will contain the TilesView that will be loaded/swapped in. Is it something like a content presenter I would have to use? If so, how? Do you have any code sample I could use? I searched the web these past days for I would code this and still no luck..

Comment: @JNate Just layout the page with a standard Grid and place the controls in that. Note that you can have multiple controls share one row/cell in a grid, just make sure that you have only one viewable at a time. That allows for them to be shown. That will be the view which to show/unshow your tiles as you call them.

Comment: I think my comment wasn't very clear. I have already created the TilesHomeView composed of a grid and my tiles are in it and working. But then I have my MainPage view where I want to call the TilesHomeView.xaml to show up in a section of that MainPage. And the section of that MainPage is what I don't know should be defined as to be able to call/contain the TilesHomeView. 
What I have initially but didnt want, is the tiles grid defined in the MainPage and be hidden or not. I made the tiles section into a whole other view(TilesHomeView.xaml) so it can be loaded/called into the MainPage at will.

Comment: Maybe this question will describe better the issue. Like what function and/or perhaps a control, will make my 2nd view appear/called into my 1st one?

Comment: @JNate Most controls such as a button can contain another control. As to any flourish which may precede the arrival of the control (or a control which does that automatically), there are none. If you want to make a control sweep in, look into using blend to create a story board for a control. Start its margin outside the screen with an opacity of zero, then 1/2 a second later change the margin to 1/2 in and opacity to 50% then after a second margin is 0 and opacity is 100%. That will give you that second control appearance which you may be looking for...